# Can't display user bio

Tags: user-meta, description

I have the ACADP listing plugin installed on my site. A registered user has a /user-listings/ page that displays all of his listings.
I would like to display this user's bio on this page, but I can't get it to work.

I tried using the [user_bio] shortcode and the following code in functions.php:

`function display_user_bio( $atts ) {     $user_slug = acadp_get_user_slug(); if ( $user_slug ) { $user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_slug ); if ( $user ) { echo get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user->ID ); } } } add_shortcode( 'user_bio', 'display_user_bio' );`

But that didn't work. Are there any ideas? Displaying the user's bio in any way is extremely important for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain as I have no experience of ACADP, but I suspect your problem is the function, `acadp_get_user_slug`. What does it do? Likely not what you think! As the following will work for the user `admim`:

```
function display_user_bio() {
    $user_slug = 'admin';
    if($user_slug != '') {
        $user = get_user_by('login', $user_slug);
        if($user) {
            return get_the_author_meta('description', $user->ID);
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode('user_bio', 'display_user_bio');
```

Note the change to `return` the required output, not `echo` it. WP shortcodes should return their output. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Pete, I tried this but it doesn't work either...

Comment: Assuming you have a user with the login slug `admin` this definitely works with the shortcode `[user_bio]`.

Comment: But after all, we are talking about displaying a bio description of all registered users on their listing archives

Comment: This option actually displays the description if you specify the slug of some registered user. However, the "user_listing" page where I insert the shortcode is the same for all users, so the description of an arbitrary user is displayed the same for everyone.

Comment: As I understand it, I need to somehow substitute the current user in the user slug in the loop. Or something like that. Unfortunately, it's hard for me to find the right option, I'm not a developer like you.

Comment: If you want to just show the current user's bio, replace `$user_slug = 'admin';` with something like `global $current_user; $user_slug = $current_user->user_login;`.

Comment: Dear Pete, not the bio of the current user, but the bio of the author whose listings are displayed on the page.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain correctly from the beginning, sorry if that's the case. This is a dynamic page that is generated by the plugin's shortcode. So I can't just post the author's bio there because then it will be the same for all users. I can only create and add another shortcode that will display the bio of the user who owns the current listings.